# How retrieve information from a SQL query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Having `createNativeQuery`

> SELECT c.name, c.breed, c.weight FROM cat c

such also

> SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID FROM Customers LEFT JOIN
>   Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID ORDER BY
>   Customers.CustomerName;

I would like to pull out information such as:

- cat.name
- cat.breed
- cat.weight

It is possible to obtain such information using Hibernate 5/JPA 2.1?

Alternatively, if it is possible to obtain these data with metadata? I found a solution to get Connection with EntityManager, then you can draw any metadata. Unfortunately, this is the solution for Hibernate 4/JPA 2.0, not work in Hibernate 5/JPA 2.1.

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
ConnectionProvider cp = sfi.getConnectionProvider();
Connection conn = cp.getConnection();
```

Comment: I think this link will help to work with any hibernate example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm

Comment: Column names. I am making an application in which the user can specify any query..

Comment: You should be able to use plain JPA query and set the result class to javax.persistence.Tuple and that makes the field/column name available. Assuming that your JPA provider fully supports the JPA 2.1 spec. Clearly if you are using a NATIVE query with cols selected then your query has the column names specified, so no need to retrieve them. You only need to retrieve them with JPQL

Comment: Yes, but the query can be any, even with a few table. I can not then set result class.

Comment: WHY can you not set a result class of Tuple??? It is a general purpose result class!

Comment: I added a second query to the question. The user can type in any query, retrieve data even with a few table. I want to let him in the later stage of mapping the fields, and for that you need to read the names of the columns.

Comment: I could ask for an example that when the query retrieves data from several different tables?

Comment: Just set the result class to Tuple.class. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: I read about it now. Unfortunately, I do not know how to apply it in my case....